# Is there any built-in way to loop over a column/lines?

Tags: import, evaluation

I have a file as following:

```
  cat data.m
  1
  2
  3
  x+y
  2 x + 3 y
```

So it contains rows containing numeric numbers or expressions,
which at this stage is not a `column` per se but  upon substitution of say `x=1` and `y=2`  it will give an output column as:

```
  cat output.m
  1
  2
  3
  3
  8
```

I want to save the whole file into this output file after substitution of `x` and `y`. Is there any way to do it? The way I was thinking is whether I can loop over the file `data.m` and in the process substitute `x` and `y`. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Block[{x = 1, y = 2},
  Export["out.m", ReadList["data.m"], "Table"]
]

 FilePrint@"out.m"
```

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   3
>   8